# gradle and react-native with fish shell

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, fish

Although I set my env in config.fish: `set ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/opt/android-sdk` gradle is still failing to read my ANDROID_HOME variable with error:

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
:app
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.RuntimeException: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getAndCheckSdkFolder(SdkHandler.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getSdkLoader(SdkHandler.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:86)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:507)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:455)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/code/AwesomeProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 71

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.521 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

How do I fix this? What shell is react-native actually using to run this? I have set my .bash_profile too

Answer (score 5):

`set` by default makes a local variable. You need `set -x ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/opt/android-sdk` to export it.